# NSTextField vertically misaligns text when using non-default typeface

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am having trouble making text fields look acceptable when using different typefaces.

See this screenshot taken from a test app I made to demonstrate the problem. It consists of a single XIB, with no code in the delegate or anywhere else. This is on OSX Mavericks with Xcode 5.1.1 but I haven't tried on other versions.

[image: Test app screenshot]

The default system font looks fine in the top text field, as you'd expect. Compare this to the one below: same exact size and shape, all I did differently was change the typeface in Interface Builder. Text is pushed downwards, and descending letters (lowercase pqjg) are clipped. The Menlo example below is also pushed downwards, though not quite as badly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If yes, are you letting the text field use its intrinsic size or are you enforcing a height via constraints? If no, are you resizing the text field to fit its content after changing the font? (You may need to slightly adjust the size manually before the Size to Fit Content menu item enables. Seems to be an IB bug.)

Answer (score 2):

A quick test shows Lucida Grande and Helvetica require 17 pixels, and Menlo requires 19 pixels:

[image: playground]

Note that this excludes the border and shadows, so you need your text view to be significantly larger than that to guarantee it will fit.

Interface Builder has been specifically designed for Lucida Grande, it knows it can get away with being too small because that font doesn't use all the space it has available. Doesn't work well with other fonts.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this a couple of different ways:

> • Enable "Uses Single Line Mode" on the Text Field Panel. When I first
>   encountered this issue it wasn't obvious that this would automatically
>   align the text vertically within an NSTextField.

or...

> • Simply adjust the size of the NSTextField using the adjustment boxes
>   that appear after you click on it. You can also adjust them through
>   the "Control" properties.

---

> [image: XCode Text Properties]